# Clickonce winforms application wont start from startmenu

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a simple Winforms application deployed via clickonce.

On my dev-machine it works.

On other machines it installs ok but it crashes when started from the startmenu.

The is no problem starting it form C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...

When crashing the error occurs when clickonce looks for a .mdb in in ...[Application Directory]\Data. However, the .mdb file is deployed in the Application Directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post how it crashes? Also, does it crash when started from the startmenu on every install on every machine or just one?

Comment: I have updated the question to accommodate your question.... "questions questions..."

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message from the 3rd party dll?

Comment: No, notthing but the Windows 7 
"... has crashed windows is searching for.."

Comment: Can you put a try/catch around the calling code and see what exception is returned? Knowing what the error actually is will help enormously in solving it - eg whether it's a path problem, a permissions problem etc.

Comment: Ok 3rd party dll operates on a .mdb file. This file is included in the project as "Content" and "Copy Always". I misinterpeted the reason for the crash it is not derived from invoking the .dll. Crash occurs whne the application is started as a Clickonce application (through startmenu) it looks for the .mdb in  ...\[Application folder]\Data but the file actually resides in the application folder. When run directly from application folder this check does not occur and hence it works. (I have updated the question accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What caused the problem:**

The .mdb file was included in the project with "Build Action = Content" and "Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always".

In application settings Publish Status for the .mdb file was set to "Include".

This deployed the .mdb file with the application files. However, the clickonce application expected the .mdb file to be deployed  in the clickonce \Data folder.

**Solution:**

In "Application Files" "Publish status" for the .mdb was set to Data File. This depolys the file to the clickonce \Data folder.

All interaction with the .mdb file through Paths was updated so that if the application was deployed the clickonce datapath was used.

```
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        this.applicationDataPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.UserAppDataPath), "Data");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using procmon to see what your application is trying to access? it may show a further dependency of your application that may have been missed.

Also if the dll in question is COM have you created the necessary manifests for the application and assembly.

HTH

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put in exception handling around calling the 3rd party dll and post the exact error you are getting. If it works when you click on the exe in the ClickOnce folder, but not when you run it as a ClickOnce application, the likely problem is that you are running something that requires more permissions than a ClickOnce application has, something that requires administrative access.